# How to run a macro regardless of local user settings

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet that is used by multiple users through the network,  the book has a macro that is supposed to run as soon as the book is opened. My issue is that some users have macros disabled so when they open the book the macro does not run. I know that disabling macros is a good security feature but I really want to enable all macros for this book regardless of the user's settings.

Is there a way to enable the macros regardless of what the user settings are?

Comment: No.  Otherwise the security settings would be pointless.  (But, I believe, you could get the network administrators to change the settings for all users to permit workbooks in certain directories to be "trusted".)

Comment: So the user settings always override the settings in the Excel book? If yes, I guess the only solution would be that each user makes the book a trusted document?

Comment: Imagine how easy it would be to propogate a virus if all that had to be done is have the virus-infected workbook say "I am trustworthy - ignore the user's desire to not trust me".  So, yes, the user settings will always take precedence over what the workbook says.

Comment: I have found it's pretty easy to get users to change settings if you tell them the how and why of it. :) And also explain them not to open just any random excel file from any random person (particularly outside the company).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a situation like this, in the company that I work at. We have a system that uses excel sheets to take a number in a series to use as their item number for design work.  The users kept grabbing each other's #'s so I wrote a macro to aid in reducing the issue, but some users didn't have macros enabled so it caused issues.

You can't enable/ disable macros that would be bad, but you could give the user a nudge.

1. First, set up a worksheet that explains to the user how to enable macros,(small disclaimer) and explain the importance of making sure that they only enable macros from known authors.
2. Next, make that sheet the only visible sheet.
3. make all the other sheets `really-hidden` and when the macro is enabled you `unhide` the sheets, and hide the explanation sheet.

If they already have macros enabled they won't ever see the explanation page.

Here is the code I used:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    'Step 1: Declare your variables
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim result As Variant

    'Step 2: Unhide the Starting Sheet
    Sheets("START").Visible = xlSheetVisible

    'Step 3: Start looping through all worksheets
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        'Step 4: Check each worksheet name
        If ws.Name <> "START" Then

            'Step 5: Hide the sheet
            ws.Visible = xlVeryHidden
        End If

    'Step 6: Loop to next worksheet
    Next ws

    'Step 7: Save the workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'Step 1: Declare your variables
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    'Step 2: Start looping through all worksheets
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        'Step 3: Unhide All Worksheets
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible

    'Step 4: Loop to next worksheet
    Next ws

    'Step 5: Hide the Start Sheet
    Sheets("START").Visible = xlVeryHidden
End Sub
```

Comment: @ R. Roe -I really like this idea but I haven't been able to come up with the right logic for handling the saving after the user turns on macros. I have, `Intro-Sheet` and `Sheet1`, with macros turned off `Sheet1` is really hidden and `Intro-Sheet` is visible & as soon as the user turns the macros on, a method is called on `open`  and `Sheet1` becomes visible and `Intro-Sheet` is hidden, no problems here. My problem is saving the state for `Sheet1` to be hidden and `Intro-Sheet` to be visible again when the sheet is closed. I have a method that is called right before closing the document...

Comment: ... but in order to save the visibility state of the sheets back to the default state, the user would need to save the changes when he/she is asked because the visibility property was changed. If the user saves it there is no problem the intro page will be shown the next time the document is opened but if the user does not save it, `Sheet1` will be visible. I could auto-save the visibility state right before closing the doc but what if the user doesn't want to save the changes she/he made, this is my issue here. How are you handling the save of the visibility to go back to the default state?

Comment: So you should handle all this in two events, in the `workbook_open` event, and the `workbook_close` event.  You should make all of your other sheets visible using a for loop and make your intro sheet `veryhidden` in the open event.  In the close event hide all of your worksheets, make them `veryhidden`, and unhide the intro sheet.  This will make it so that if macros are enabled they will never see the intro sheet, but if they aren't enabled it will force them to enable the macros.  If you're still having problems I can post some code.

Comment: @ R. Roe-My issue is for instance when the user modifies the content from `Sheet1` but then he decides not to save those changes and clicks the close window button which will prompt him with the question, do you want to save changes?If he says no, the visibility will NOT change back to the defaults.I could automate the save on close but then I will be saving things that the user may not want to save. Would you mind showing the code you are currently using in your `workbook_close` method? Or maybe both? I'm curious to see how you are using a `for loop`.

Comment: I've posted the code, and yes that would be an issue because the worksheet has to save before it closes.